# What is the right value to set the border property in CSS to remove it?

Tags: css

I've just noticed myself using both `border: none` and `border: 0` to reset a  border in the cascade.

Is there a One True Way™ to reset a border that has already been set?

Answer (score 1):

As you should probably be aware, `border` is a shorthand property. What you may not realize (and, in fact, is new to me too) is that those values do not pertain to the shorthand property itself but each belongs to one of the longhand CSS border properties (technically, these are shorthands for all sides as well but I won't get to that):

- `none` is a value for `border-style`
- `0` is a value for `border-width`

As an additional note, each of these values is the *initial value* of its respective longhand property. In other words, the declarations `border: none` and `border: 0` are functionally equivalent — setting `border: none` will also set `border-width` to `0`, and setting `border: 0` will also set `border-style` to `none`.

So there is no "right" way to declare the lack of a border using the `border` shorthand. Use whichever makes more sense to you.

Comment: Well I was wondering if any which one was the right way... thought I may as well be doing it right instead of relying on a browser quirk (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Completely up to you, some say one way, some say the other. The `border: none` is the 'technical' way to do it because 'none' is a listed allowed value for border, but `border: 0` is just basically a short-hand version to save a few extra characters. I don't even know which one I use, it doesn't really bother me either way.

**Edit:** Here's another good conversation on a similar topic (0 vs 0em)...
[CSS difference between 0 and 0em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935107/css-difference-between-0-and-0em)

Answer (score -1):

technically, it should be border: 0 <-- if you are using the short hand,

OR border-style:none; <-- I prefer this, but if a few char matters...

---

The shorthand is border: [width] [style] [color];

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp (or the formal specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties)

Note: As pointed out by below comment. `border: 0px;` is redundant but `border: 1px;` is not. Units (em, ex, px, etc) are not optional when value > 0.

Comment: "technically, it should be border: 0px" No - the px unit is redundant.

Comment: you are correct, I will make an edit, units are optional for 0's.